# Opening only some functions from a module in Reason

Tags: reason

I'm trying to do something like this in Reason:

```
let {map, fold_left} = List;
let {log} = Js;

let list = [1,2,3];
list |> map(i => i + 1) |> fold_left((p,c) => p+c, 0) |> log;
```

Basically, I want to import only a couple of functions from a module. Is that possible in Reason.

Currently I do it like this:

```
let map = List.map;
let fold_left = List.fold_left;
let log = Js.log;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Discord, courtesy of @octachron

```
let (map,fold_left) = List.(map, fold_left)
```